# How to use python regex effectivly based on conditionals

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand to get the repeated words based on matching their last 3 characters or three characters from a string.

```
var1 = "we have hotel in Singapore and we have motel as well in Singapore, please let us know about your plan of visit and we will tell you more about venue and locations around us."
```

### Expected some like below:

Words having their last 3 character same should be returning like.

```
(hotel, motel, singapore, about, have)
```

Trial:

when i'm testing that over [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) as  `(\w[a-zA-Z]tel)` it gets me the word  `hotel` and `motel`, Similarly ..

```
(\w*[a-zA-Z]ore)  <-- this gives me `Singapore`
(\w*[a-zA-Z]out)  <-- this gives me `about`
(\w*[a-zA-Z]ve)   <-- this gives me  `have`
(we\s)            <-- this gives me  `we`
```

Now, while i am combining them altogether like `(\w[a-zA-Z]tel)(\w*[a-zA-Z]ore)(\w*[a-zA-Z]out)(\w*[a-zA-Z]ve)(we\s)` it doesn't gives anything.

I am Just trying hard to get it but not getting a right solution.

**EDIT:**

As i am giving the last `three` characters hard coded, Is it possible to achieve this without providing these and evaluate the same.

Comment: It is not clear about `we`, you are extracting a known word?  Right now, you could as well use `re.findall(r'\b(\w*[a-zA-Z](?:ore|out|ve)|we)\b', text)`

Comment: Are you looking for a separator? It's the character '|'. This wil match one regex or the other: `(\w[a-zA-Z]tel)|(\w*[a-zA-Z]ore)|(\w*[a-zA-Z]out)|(\w*[a-zA-Z]ve)|(we\s)`

Comment: What does "As i am giving the last three characters hard coded, Is it possible to achieve this without providing these and evaluate the same." mean? Do you mean you want to extract all words with at least 3 letters? `set(re.findall(r'\w*[^\W\d_]{3}\b', text))`?

Comment: Ok, do you want `set([x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b[a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]{3})\b(?=.*\1\b)', text)])`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this seems to be near but it looks like it also capturing the words which are not repeating like `well`, i like only repeating once based on 3 chars.

Comment: It seems like you want to extract any repeating 3+ letter words and remove dupes, see https://ideone.com/SFz7RQ

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  that's true .. that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b([a-zA-Z]{3,})\b(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Kb8YI/1). *Details*:

- `\b([a-zA-Z]{3,})\b` - a whole word consisting of three or more ASCII letters
- `(?=.*\b\1\b)` - that is followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and the same word as a whole word.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SFz7RQ):

```py
import re
var1 = "we have hotel in Singapore and we have motel as well in Singapore, please let us know about your plan of visit and we will tell you more about venue and locations around us."
print(set([x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b([a-zA-Z]{3,})\b(?=.*\b\1\b)', var1)]))
# => {'Singapore', 'have', 'about', 'and'}
```

Here, `set(...)` will remove any duplicate matches returned by the `re.finditer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor, this what i was looking for exactly.